# How to avoid Ionic cursor blinking?

Tags: ionic-framework

IonicFramework Question:

Have a standard input text field, which when focused gets this ugly blinking blue cursor. The worse is that this blinking stays on even when the page is scrolled, and shows through other modal elements like header and sub-header.

Answer (score 1):

```
-moz-text-blink: none 

-moz-text-blink: none !important
```

(if it is overriding from child element.)

Comment: Manaswi - Sorry, this did not work in the iOS build from Ionic.